# Windows Phone BETA 805a0194 error

Tags: windows-phone-7, beta-testing

I get this error message. Other people refer to this error message as well, where it turns out their App has not been published yet. Ofcourse I understand Windows will give me 404 when the app hasn't been published yet. Only problem is: MSDN App HUB states that it has already been published, but I still keep getting this error. It has been well over the 2 hour - margin in which MSDN says they will publish it. Also, I have the deep link, something that I shouldn't have, had they not published the app, I reckon? Any idead on what may cause this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If usually takes longer than 2 hours for the app to be available after being published. I would suggest waiting for 24 hours until starting to worry. As long as your app is not visible in the Marketplace search, it should be ok.

Comment: Yes, it is noe available, and without any problem =3 thanks! 
I have another question though, Windows states that submitting the app takes up to two hours, and it has been flagged as "published".
Now, one of the main reasons that I choose Beta, other than not every user being able to view it, is the fast distribution time ( which was stated as being two hours ), but it does take longer ( up to 24 hours, according to you? )

I want my client to dl and install the app as close to immediate as possible.  So, my question boils down to this:
Why is this extra 22 hour period?

Comment: No clue. I didn't even know it was stated somewhere that you could publish under 2 hours. I know the 24 hours delay from my experience. I think you'll have to ask Microsoft directly for this one.

Comment: If you get a response, please copy it here as a comment. I'm interested in knowing more :)